# Record Screencast of Remote Presenter

Tags: screen-casting

For some time now I've been looking for screencast software that can record someone presenting on another computer. The application is for a commercial screencast recording company that comes in and records screencasts of lectures, product demos, and keynotes for other companies.

The problem I run into is that all the screencast software I've seen records only the local screen. That doesn't work--we can't load screencast software on the presenter's computer. What we've used so far is Wirecast and Desktop Presenter. Desktop Presenter goes on the presenter's computer, and Wirecast goes on our recording cart computer. This works, but it produces videos that are difficult to edit (we use QuickTime Pro 7 to edit without re-compressing). If we had something like [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) that also had remote recording (i.e. Desktop Presenter)--that would be perfect. Anyone know of a product like this? If no product like I've described exists, can you think of another creative solution? It would be ideal if the solution can track and zoom in on mouse movement like many screencast products do (i.e. Camtasia Studio and ScreenFlow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, one, install software on the presenter's system that can encode and send a video feed to another system.  This is in-effect going to be a screen casting application, even if the feed is only forwarded to another system to be packaged.

The other option is to actually capture the raw output from the presenter's system through a frame grabber or video interface of some type.  This is the least invasive way, but then have no idea about cursor position or the like.

There is no solution that can connect to another computer and grab whatever is on their screen without putting software on that computer.  You can however do something minimally invasive like putting a VNC server that can run from a USB stick without installing and then connect to that VNC server and run the screen capture off the VNC client on a system you control.

Comment: I guess installing some software is OK. I install Desktop Presenter right now, and that usually works out OK. I would be OK with the VNC option too, but mouse tracking still wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: @watkipet - probably not.  Your best bet is probably to just use a screencasting application that works for the initial needs in the background and then have it send to a system that can actually do the recording, but I'm not sure what would do that specifically.  I normally run the presentation side of things and just do video captures of the output we send to the projector or even run the on screen graphics from my machine and just watch when they advance on a preview monitor.  (So when they hit the next button, I do the same on mine, but this only works if they aren't pointing to things.)